# Windows 8 ListView Control not showing up when placed inside a CSS Grid

Tags: css, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winjs

I am following along the Microsoft tutorial "Quickstart: Adding a ListView" (Can't post link because of spam prevention) for Windows 8 app development and I am attempting to simply show the raw data from my array in ListView format. I have slightly modified the tutorial so that I am using CSS Grids to structure the page (as Microsoft recommends, I believe). The problem I am having is that when the ListView is situated outside of a Grid, it show's and display's perfectly, but, when located inside a CSS Grid, will not show up on my app. I have very limited knowledge in both CSS Grids and the new Windows 8 platforms so I am sure it is a simple mistake that I have made. Below is my CSS and HTML code, all the Javascript should be identical to that used in the Microsoft tutorial...

http://pastebin.com/cgV5PHnf - HTML

http://pastebin.com/HvVPuhkG - CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your HTML and CSS, verbatim, data is showing fine for me.  This is my tempData.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var items = new WinJS.Binding.List();
    items.push({ value1: "foo", value2: "bar" });
    items.push({ value1: "foo2", value2: "bar2" });

    WinJS.Namespace.define("TempData", {
        itemList: items.dataSource
    });
})();
```

Note, I included `dataSource` in the definition of `itemList`, since your `data-win-options` did NOT include it (the [Quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465496.aspx) pulls that into the attribute).  Without it though you'd be getting a pretty noticeable exception, so suspect you're doing the same in your `TempData` definition.

One thing you could try is [DOM Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441474#InteractiveDebugging) in Visual Studio or open the application in Blend and use [Interactive Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj129413.aspx) to see if there is some sort of unexpected CSS class overriding.

Comment: Using your tempData.js my app works perfectly, so I adapted my existing data to your format, which is different to what is in the Quickstart and now my app works! Thanks...